# Regex describing a regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, schema, jsonschema

I am surprised that an answer to this is not easily found.

I am in the process of making a JSON schema. I have an object and one of it's properties is a string containing a regex pattern. This property must contain only regex.

So, this question is realistically two questions in one:

What is the regex pattern that describes regex patterns (javascript-compatible please)?

Secondly, how do I apply this to JSON schema (in the `"pattern"` property or even in the `"patternProperty"`<sup>1</sup> property)?

<sup>1</sup>: I have no idea what purpose would require you to apply this in `"patternProperty"`, but someone out there could find it useful

**NOTE:** Since, JSONschema is JSON and JSON is JavaScript-based, JavaScript scripters may find the solution (to the JSONschema-side of the question), as well as the problem, useful in their scripts.

Comment: Regexes can have nested parentheses.  Therefore, they are not describable by a regular expression.  Sorry.

Comment: @SLaks good point. I encourage you to put that as an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27984941/648265

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/172303/11107541 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexes can have nested parentheses.

Therefore, they are not describable by a regular expression.
Sorry.

Comment: Python PyPi regex module, Boost, PCRE, Ruby and .NET regex engines can match nested parentheses, JS engine can't.